# map/set iterator not incrementable when AppVerifier runs

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, application-verifier

I'm trying to run an application which handles clients over the network under application verifier.
The application holds a map to maintain the clients, and a semaphore with maximum count of 1 to lock the map.
Without the verifier it runs with no error, but when the verifier is attached, I get the following runtime error:

> map/set iterator not incrementable

for the following code:

```
Lock l(_mapLock); // This object uses a semaphore for synchronization 

MapType::iterator it; 
ClientInfo info; 
it = _clientsMap.begin(); 
for (it = _clientsMap.begin(); it != _clientsMap.end(); it++) { 
  (*it).second->getInfo(&info); 
  if (strcmp(info.ip, clientIp.c_str()) == 0) { 
    return DUPLICATE_CLIENT; 
  } 
}
```

Any idea for a possible cause?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can `getInfo()` ever modify `_clientsMap`?

Comment: BTW, you don't need to initialise `it` twice, and `++it` would be better than `it++`.

Comment: Possible read about this (duplicates) [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997503/map-set-iterator-not-incrementablemap-set-iterator-not-incrementable) [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764058/map-set-iterators-not-incrementable-error-in-c)